# filtering with multiple conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering

I am trying to filter data based on input and it works fine but I want add an extra condition to it. It should return if titel or another value (for example sendFrom) is given.

```
 const newData = masterDataSource.filter(function (item) {

    const itemData = item.titel  ? item.titel.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
    const textData = text.toUpperCase();
    return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
  });
```

I tried adding some operators but it didn´t worked out as planed

```
     const newData = masterDataSource.filter(function (item) {

    const itemData = item.titel || item.sendFrom ? item.titel.toUpperCase() || item.sendFrom.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
    const textData = text.toUpperCase();
    return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
  });
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly did not work out? And what is uppercase of `""`?

Comment: ''..toUpperCase() was unnecessary, sorry. I can still filter by titel but not by sendFrom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're after you would want something like:

```js
const itemData = item.titel ? item.titel.toUpperCase() : (item.sendFrom ? item.sendFrom.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase());
```

Parentheses are not required, but I added them to make it easier to get the logic.

Also, `''.toUpperCase()` doesn't make much sense, it's the same as `''`.

You could replace the initial condition with

```js
const itemData = (item.titel  && item.titel.toUpperCase()) || '';
```

and the revised version:

```js
const itemData = (item.titel  && item.titel.toUpperCase()) || (item.sendFrom  && item.sendFrom.toUpperCase()) || '';
```

Again, parentheses are not required.

References:
[Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#conditional_ternary_operator)
[Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#logical_operators)

Comment: `(item.titel  && item.titel.toUpperCase()) || (item.sendFrom  && item.sendFrom.toUpperCase()) || '';` can be shortened to `(item.titel || item.sendFrom)?.toUpperCase() ?? ''`

Comment: I think it should be `(item.titel || item.sendFrom || '').toUpperCase()` since if there's neither `.titel` nor `.sendForm` you call `undefined.toUpperCase()` which results in an error.

Comment: nope ... notice the usage of both operators, the [Optional chaining ( `?.` )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and  the [Nullish coalescing operator ( `??` )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). One wants to exit es early as possible and does not want to have as a fallback variant an additional avoidable `''.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Wow, you're perfectly right! I didn't even know that `?.` existed and I'm using js for 15 years!

Answer (score 1):

You could collect the wanted properties in an array and iterate them while checking the values.

```
const newData = masterDataSource.filter(({ titel = '', sendFrom = '' }) => 
    [titel, sendFrom].some(s => s.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase()))
);
```